# My Oxygen25 midi keyboard wont work with Pro Tools 9, help..?

Tags: logic-pro, pro-tools, mac, avid

So, I have Pro Tools 9 and a 3rd Gen Oxygen25 midi keyboard (usb). Both are made by Avid, yet I can't get them to work together.. The keyboard even works with Logic Pro 9, just not Pro Tools 9...

I'm running OS X 10.6.8 on a Mac Book Pro (15-inch). Also, it's Pro Tools 9.0.2[image][image]

Comment: Have you tried following [these configuration instructions on the M-audio tech support site](http://www.m-audio.com/index.php?do=support.faq&ID=3bd39018a88f65191feeee50b5952c24)?

Comment: @NeilFein, you're right!  I've added more in my answer below.

Comment: I'm trying this with a yamaha and am having the same problem even when the receive and send to are set as it.

Answer (score 1):

@neilfein is correct in his comment.  The mistake you have made is to set **send to** to be Xpand2.  This should in fact be set to **Oxygen 25**.  This is because Pro Tools needs to know where to receive input from, and where to send output to, in terms of your keyboard (i.e., it needs two-way communication).

In a USB-based keyboard, this doesn't really make logical sense - there is only one cable which acts as both MIDI in and MIDI out.

So why should you have to make these choices at all?  These options exist because you could (in theory) be connecting your keyboard via traditional MIDI cables, meaning that your **receive from** and **send to** ports could actually be different physical MIDI interfaces.  In this scenario, these settings make more logical sense.

To summarise, you need to set both your **receive from** and **send to** to **Oxygen 25**.  Then it should work.

The [link](http://www.m-audio.com/index.php?do=support.faq&ID=3bd39018a88f65191feeee50b5952c24) that @NeilFein provided also contains handy tips on using the MIDI controllers on your Oxygen 25 to control Pro Tools.